# How to Add a String to a nested Arraylist?

Tags: android, string, arraylist

I have this code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> row = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> column = new ArrayList<String>();
```

my problem is I can't add String to it.
How can I add String from a TextView(in Android)?

Comment: do you want add string to column or row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> row = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> column = new ArrayList<String>();
row.add(column);
column.add(myString);

String theString = row.get(0).get(0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have declared your `TextView` in xml (replace `myTextView` with your TextView's id):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
int index = 0;//change to index in row that you want to modify
String text = tv.getText().toString();
ArrayList<String> col = row.get(index);
if (col == null) {
    col = new ArrayList<String>();
    col.add(text);
    row.add(col);
}
else {
    col.add(text);
}
```